# PowerGUI Script Editor, How to pass parameters?

Tags: powershell, powergui

I'm trying to pass a parameter to my application like (filename.exe -Param Value) but no luck.

I'm trying to capture the parameter with this

```
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$message)
write-host $message
```

Using the command line to execute the compiled script I try to pass in the parameter but it wont work, below is an example. I've also tried with --message, /message nothing works.

```
C:\Users\OptiPlex\Desktop>Read_Host_Secure_String.exe -message Hello
cmdlet Read_Host_Secure_String.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
message:
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the input, I did indeed, but that´s no the problem unfortunately.

Comment: You're invoking an `.exe` file, but the prompt is being put up by a `.ps1` file. Without knowing how the former calls the latter, it's hard to diagnose your problem.

Comment: The .exe is compiled by PowerGUI Script Editor, I won´t know how it compiles the ps1...

Comment: I'm not familiar with PowerGUI, but it seems that at least with the particular `.exe` you've created pass-through arguments are either unsupported or - perhaps, I don't know - require special syntax.

Comment: yeah, will be one of the two, hopefully someone can confirm it, I´m hoping for the latter ..

Comment: Best asking on PowerGUI forums. It could well be that parameneters have to be passed in a soemhting like `-Param` switch rather than using the original variable

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is
Myfile.exe -arguments -message Hello